# Navigate to another page and print that page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php script (process.php) in which i do all my stuff and generate html output like this.

**PROCESS.PHP**

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   //Rest of my php code is here.
   echo "FINAL";
   file_put_contents('record.html', ob_get_contents());
   ob_end_flush();
   //it will write a file named 'record.html' in the same directory.
?>
```

Now what i want when any user open this process.php file , he will be redirected to record.html and print option shows up automatically.

Whether user is print the document or cancel / close the print option, the page should be closed automatically.

Comment: Dear, must clearly define your question. Clearly define question can give you better and accurate answer.

Comment: which part is not understandable. @MuhammadIrfan

Comment: Dailague Print.. does not give any sense of functionality.

Comment: Can you please define your problem? I can't parse "Now interesting thing is that even if print the document or cancel / close the print dialog. That page should be closed automatically."

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan my bad let me correct it.

Comment: dailogue print for process.php or record.html ?

Comment: dialogue print for record.html @MuhammadIrfan

Comment: Is there anyone who can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code will fullfill your requirement but that is not 100% efficient. But you can use it for your work.

```
setTimeout(function(){var ww = window.open(window.location, '_self'); 
ww.close()},100); 
window.print();
```

---

if have any query about code than can ask. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this one is you could use javascript window.print when you load this page to print then you could link back from the age before you opened this print page using window.location.href="link of any age excluding this print page" or you can open this age to another window if you want using window.open().
try this too.

window.print();

window.location.href="another age"; // or window.close() to totally close window